# how to not set default gateway after android dial an vpn connection

Tags: vpn

As the question says, I found in iOS there is an option "send all traffic", if you unselect it, the traffic won't go through the VPN connection, the windows ipv4 setting have a similar option, but I found no such option in android, anyone knows how not to set the default gw in android.

Answer (score 0):

In the phone's settings tap, Network & internet and then Advanced and then VPN settings then tap [forget](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9089766?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdisconnect-or-forget-a-vpn) or are you looking for more of a automated script to do it